# Wich Shebang should you use in a shell sript?

Tags: shell, snmp, shell-scripting, zabbix

Sorry, this is maybe a stupid question, but I am new to shell scripts.

I have a file called `oem-device-name.sh`.
I need to execute an external check for Zabbix:
https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/5.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/external

The script itself is just 1 line, it is only an snmpget command:

`snmpget -v 1 -c public -Oa -Ov -OQ 172.28.132.44:31161 BSS-RCP-MIB::oem-device-name.0`

Wich Shebang should you recommend for my snmpget?
And does it makes a difference if you write 
`#!\bin\sh` or `#!\bin\bash` in a `.sh` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#!/bin/sh uses whatever login shell the user currently has set. Most default to bash but this is not guaranteed

#!/bin/bash is used for (predictably) bash scripts

files with .sh suffix are somewhat deprecated and largely unnecessary - just name the script what you want without it

If you're using bash, use #!/bin/bash unless you foresee yourself (or other users) needing to run the script using a different shell (like csh)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But if I look to the documentation from Zabbix (see link), I have to use the deprecated shell scripts. So I have to use #!/bin/sh ?

Comment: Don't know about Zabbix. But in general you should be fine using #!/bin/sh and calling it script.sh